# Looping through ordered Magento products

Tags: magento

I am trying to create an extension that simply loops through products that were ordered. I'm extremely new to Magento. I set everything up, and tested it by having it log `it worked` to my system log. Now whenever I try to change that to actually loop through the products, I get a weird error:

```
2015-09-02T19:47:55+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 4039
```

Here's my observer:

```
<?php
class Test_Productorderlog_Model_Observer {

     public function sales_order_place_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
     {
         $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

         foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            Mage::log($product , null , 'system.log');
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the event `checkout_submit_all_after` in this case. As far as a I know `sales_order_place_after` is triggered when you have placed an order  using *Multishipping* but `checkout_submit_all_after` will always get triggered.

```
<global>
<events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <myaction_save_order>
                    <class>test_productorderlog/observer</class>
                    <method>sales_order_place_after</method>
                </myaction_save_order>
            </observers>
           </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

and use

```
<?php
class Test_Productorderlog_Model_Observer {

     public function sales_order_place_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
     {
         $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

         foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            Mage::log(print_r($product,true) , null , 'myorderedproducts.log');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error, but there is nothing in the log now... I changed myorderedproducts.log to system.log

Comment: Nevermind... User error, I was missing a closing tag ha. Thanks!